# extract unique values across multiple columns in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of names in column A and each name has a country in column B which is either Home or Host as specified in Column C. I need to look down the list of names then across to the country, then across to the Home/Host column and paste whether it relates to home or host in either column E or F. There could be a Home and Host for one person but sometimes only a Home or a Host.

The screenshot is how I would like the finished result to look like and I have manually entered the results into column E and F.

I have tried numerous index match combinations but nothing has worked so far. I have also tried to update this
[Loop through a column and based on the cell value copy the data to two other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69613733/loop-through-a-column-and-based-on-the-cell-value-copy-the-data-to-two-other-col) which works perfectly for its intended use but not for what I am now looking to do and my VBA skills are not great so I cant edit it.

So my question is can I just use a Formula to achieve the desired result or would VBA be the best option and if so can someone please help.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: This is the classic two column lookup.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another/42493697#42493697

Comment: I appreciate you pointing me in the right direction on this, I got this working using the =FILTER function as you suggested in your link above. Cheers.